# ASP.NET Core with Razor Pages: Return value from DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I have a web app that allows me to pull names from my Customer table inside my database and print them out in a drop-down menu. I can then select the name in the list, but I don't know how to actually implement returning that name so that I can plug it in elsewhere on the website.

This is the code I have for my CustomerPage.cshtml.cs class:

```
namespace CDInsightsWeb.Pages.Customer
{
public class CustomerPageModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly ConnectionStringClass _db;

    public CustomerPageModel(ConnectionStringClass db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    public List<Model.Customer> DisplayData { get; set; }

    public async Task OnGet()
    {
        DisplayData = await _db.Customer.ToListAsync();
    }
    public async Task OnPost()
    {
        return RedirectToPage("/Assessment/AssessmentPage", new { Customer.name });
    }
}
}
```

In the CustomerPage.cshtml, I have a line that displays and populates the DropDownList:

```
@page
@model CDInsightsWeb.Pages.Customer.CustomerPageModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "CustomerPage";
}

<h1>Select A Customer</h1>
<div class="text-center">
    <hr />
    @Html.DropDownList("name", new SelectList(Model.DisplayData, "customer_id", "name"), "Select Name")
</div>
<div>
    <a asp-page="/Customer/CreateCustomer">Create a Customer</a>
</div>
```

How might I return the value I select from this list? Also if any extra info is needed, just let me know, thanks!

Edit: Added the full code for CustomerPage.cshtml
Edit2: Added code for OnPost method

Comment: I think you want to bind name...  [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
        public string name { get; set; }    In your controller you can access that... but you should post your full .cshtml file so we can see how the form is sending data.

Comment: Alright I can do that. I tried to post the whole file before but I couldn't get it to stay on it's original look.

Comment: You need a form in there... and/or use javascript to post the value...  if you use javascript you won't need a submit button and can either post the entire form's data, or just send the specific value.  If you have a submit button, just use <form method="post">@Html...<input type="submit" value = "Choose Customer"></form>  Then make your OnPost method in the controller.  ( you'll create a Customer object and bind that... include helpers on cshtml page to display... initially it'll show empty or the default choice for customer.)

Comment: Would you be able to elaborate a little more on the OnPost method? More specifically, what type would it have to be and how do I bind it?

Comment: the two main ways to transmit information are GET and POST.  They are different ways to send query variables to a page. (different types of requests to a server)  You can see GET variables as values appended to the URL... page.htm?name=value&name2=value2, etc...  your method there "OnGet" occurs when a GET is sent to the page.  When a POST happens these values are sent via POST and are not visible in the URL.  So in your controller you'd have " public async Task OnPost()"  and your logic goes there.  (lookup your customer and return the page)

Comment: You can also move DisplayData into the constructor and bind it to the page.  All the get method has to do is return the page.

Comment: Thank you for all your help pcalkins. I understand what I have to do here, but not how to implement it. Sorry for the slowness on my part, but how do I look up my customer and return the page and what is binding?

Comment: binding will automatically set a variable or class to values that are sent via GET or POST...  both htmlhelpers in your .cshtml file and the .cs file "know" what those binded values are.   (Many times they're tied to your models... data models and view models.  Your view model is basically the page and form fields... the .cshtml file... the data model is usually your data classes...) It's really going to help you if you run through this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/razor-pages-start?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

Answer (score 2):

Change below code according to your need:

Code behind:

```
    [BindProperty]
    public List<Customer> DisplayData { get; set; }

    public IActionResult OnGet()
    {
        DisplayData = new List<Customer>();
        DisplayData.Add(new Customer { customer_id = "101", name = "Arun" });
        DisplayData.Add(new Customer { customer_id = "102", name = "Sonu" });
        return Page();
    }

    public IActionResult OnPost(string name)
    {
        return RedirectToPage("/Assessment/AssessmentPage", new { name });
    }
```

View :

```
<h1>Select A Customer</h1>
<form method="post">
    <div class="text-center">
        <hr />
        @Html.DropDownList("name", new SelectList(Model.DisplayData, "name", "name"), "Select Name")
    </div>
    <div>
       <input value="submit" type="submit"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

Output :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the view; put the dropdown inside form tag, add input of type submit

In the code behind; add inside the action input parameter ex. *(string name)*

Comment: I'm very new to ASP.NET and Razor Pages so I'm not sure what you mean by "In the code behind; add inside the action input parameter ex. (string name)". Could you explain it a little less vague?

Comment: you already have the input parameter name... they mis-typed there.  The parameter name will be sent by your pulldown menu once it's inside a form/posted or otherwise sent via javascript.

Comment: Ok I believe I added the binding for the customer name and returning the page in this line: ```return RedirectToPage("/Assessment/AssessmentPage", new { Customer.name });```. But I get an error now with the method type "Task". Thoughts?

Comment: you still need to lookup the customer and bind it to the page...  and not sure why you are redirecting... aren't you going to use the same page to display the customer's data?  If you wanted another page, just use the form's action to post to a different page.  (<form method="post" asp-page="/Assessment/AssessmentPage">)